# How to read an environment variable in Kotlin?

Tags: environment-variables, kotlin

I'd like to get a certain value from an environment variable in my Kotlin app, but I can't find anything about reading environment variables in the [core libraries](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html) documentation.

I'd expect it to be under [kotlin.system](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/index.html) but there's really not that much there.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

It is really easy to get a environment value if it exists or a default value by using the elvis operator in kotlin:

```kotlin
val envVar: String = System.getenv("varname") ?: "default_value"
```

Answer (score 27):

You could always go down this approach:

```
val envVar : String? = System.getenv("varname")
```

Though, to be fair, this doesn't feel particularly idiomatic, as you're leveraging Java's System class, not Kotlin's.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "leveraging Java's System class". Kotlin has a strong emphasis on Java interop and when you're targeting the JVM, it's expected to use Java APIs.

Comment: Java's system class returns a String which in fact may be null

Answer (score 8):

And if you want to handle env var which do exists but is empty:

```
val myEnv = (System.getenv("MY_ENV") ?: "").ifEmpty { "default_value" }
```

(see edit history for previos versions)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the kotlin extension Konfig

[Konfig - A Type Safe Configuration API for Kotlin](https://github.com/npryce/konfig)

Konfig provides an extensible, type-safe API for configuration properties gathered from multiple sources — built in resources, system properties, property files, environment variables, command-line arguments, etc.

For example: `Key("http.port", intType)`

Comment: Yeah, how do we use envs with that? No doc?

Comment: @PedroD The keys in the example, are built from various sources, with env vars probably having priority in case of conflicts.